# We have never been told what the ECHO acronym means, right?

Tags: borderlands-series

We have never been told what the ECHO acronym means, right?

In the first game, Claptrap calls it ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYuA0.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHwYs.png)):

> ... ECHO communication device and heads-up display ...

So, it could be recursive...

**E**CHO **C**ommunicator and **H**eads-up **O**verlay

or something.

But we don't *know*, right?

Answer (score -3):

In game nope but it has been hinted at that it stands for Each Citizen Has One since you cannot start the game without it and everyone seems to have them and leaves recordings everywhere but that's just conjecture really.